# Do any of the reaper troops count as synthetics against skills?

Tags: mass-effect-3

For the purpose of skills like *Sabotage* and *Overload* do any of the reaper troops count as synthetics?

I feel like some of them should, since they're clearly robotic (partially at least). However, I've been trying to sabotage *Marauders* and haven't had any success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the Reaper ground forces are considered Synthetic - the only mechanical enemies in the game susceptible to the "hack" part of Sabotage are Geth and Cerberus turrets. (Ha! Taste of your own medicine, punk engineers!) You can also hack Cerberus Atlas, though against these behemoths, Sabotage has diminishing returns.

Marauders should lose their shields to overload like anything else, but they're not robots, so no hacking.